# Where have I to insert my user credential for this custom user provider (performing a REST WS authentication) in my Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am absolutly new in **PHP** and **Laravel**, I came from Java.

I am trying to follow this tutorial to implement a custom user provider:

https://blog.georgebuckingham.com/laravel-52-auth-custom-user-providers-drivers/

I briefly expain what I need: my **Laravel** application is only a f**ront end application**, all the business logic, included the user authentication, is performed by a **Java back end application** that exposes **REST web services**.

Performing a call to:

```
http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login
```

and passing username and password as **basic authentication** I obtain a **JSON response** like this that represent the logged user:

```
{
  "userName": "Painkiller",
  "email": "painkiller@gmail.com",
  "enabled": true
}
```

So, in my Laravel application, I have to perform this call and then parse the previous returned JSON object to generate the authenticated object into the front end application session.

I think that the previous **custom user provider** is the neater and most natural solution to do it, but I am finding some difficulties and I have many doubts about how do it in my project.

I am using Larave 5.3 version.

I have implemented all the **4 steps** of the previous tutorial and I think that I have correctly replaced the user provider with my **custom user provider**.

Now I have the following doubts (because the code provided in the example is not related to a real case but in the last steps it only shows stubbed version of classes).

PROBLEMS:

**FIRST PROBLEM:** 
In the **Stage 3** (**Create a user class**) it seems to me that he is creating a **model user class** that have to contains the information of the logged user, so I think that it have to hold these 3 fields: **username**, **email** and **enabled** contained in the JSON object returned by my back end REST web service:

```
{
  "userName": "Painkiller",
  "email": "painkiller@gmail.com",
  "enabled": true
}
```

Is my intuition correct? or am I missing something?

At this time my **User** class only contains the stubbed methods version:

```
<?php

namespace App\Authentication;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class User implements Authenticatable {
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        // Return the name of unique identifier for the user (e.g. "id")
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        // Return the unique identifier for the user (e.g. their ID, 123)
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        // Returns the (hashed) password for the user
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        // Return the token used for the "remember me" functionality
    }

    /**
     * @param  string $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        // Store a new token user for the "remember me" functionality
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        // Return the name of the column / attribute used to store the "remember me" token
    }
}
```

So what exactly have I to do? Have I only to insert the previous fields (**username**, **email** and **enabled*) and the related getter and setter methods? (So this object will put in the session with these information)? Is it right or am I missing something?

**SECOND PROBLEM:**
In the **STEP 4** related to the **creation a UserProvider class** I am creating the **UserProvider** class.

It seems to me that this is where I have to retrieve the logged user (if the user is authenticated in the systemo) or an error message if the user is not authenticated. So basically it should be where I have to call my back end REST web service (passing the credential inserted into the login form) to obtain the user information used to create the previous **User** instance. Is it right?

So this is my **UserProvider** implementing the **Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider interface**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Authentication;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider as IlluminateUserProvider;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use function GuzzleHttp\json_encode;
use function GuzzleHttp\json_decode;

class UserProvider implements IlluminateUserProvider
{
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        // TODO: Implement retrieveById() method.
    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        // TODO: Implement retrieveByToken() method.
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
        // TODO: Implement updateRememberToken() method.
    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        // TODO: Implement retrieveByCredentials() method.

        $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client

        $response = $client->post('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
            [
                'auth' => [
                    'Painkiller',
                    'pswd'
                ]
            ]);


    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        // TODO: Implement validateCredentials() method.
    }

}
```

So I think that I have to put my webservice call in this method retrieveByCredentials(), this one:

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    // TODO: Implement retrieveByCredentials() method.

    $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client

    $response = $client->post('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
        [
            'auth' => [
                'Painkiller',
                'pswd'
            ]
        ]);

}
```

For simplicity, at this time I have hard coded the credential of an existing user returned by the web service doing performing an http request, so for any credential inserted by the user in the login form will always retrieve this user (I want to do a test...then I will integrate with the inserted credential).

Now my doubt is: have I only to parse the JSON response and set the related field of a **User** instance that represents the user information retrieved by the web service?

Ok and now...the final problem:

I start my Laravel application by the statment: **php artisan serve**. It starts with no error.

My problem is: I have created all this custom authentication mechanism that should authenticate the inserted credential calling my back end REST web service but...**where have I to insert these credential?** Where is the username and password login form?

Reading online it seems to me that I can access to a Laravel login page using this URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/login
```

but I am obtaining this error message instead the login page:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 766
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 621
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Betrivius\WorkSpace\betriviusExtranet\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Why? What am I missing? Where can I insert my credential to test if my custom user provides works as I expect?

**EDIT 1:**: This is the output of the **php artisan route:list** statment:

```
> C:\xampp\php\php.exe artisan route:list
+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action                                                | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | App\Http\Controllers\LoginBetriviusController@index   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure                                               | api,auth:api |
|        | POST     | doLogin  |      | App\Http\Controllers\LoginBetriviusController@doLogin | web          |
+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

As you can see it doesn't contain the standard Laravel login. The **LoginBetriviusController** is another controller used in the implementation of a custom login that not use custom user provider concept and I have to remove it. Why? I also noticed that my project seems not contain the laravel login view. Why? Is it not automatically provided by Laravel? Or have I to create\enable in some way?

Comment: As for your last issue, double check `php artisan route:list` to see if its the correct route. If I recall correctly it should be `/auth/login`. Another thing. I think the views are created when running `php artisan make:auth`, however, this includes that you'll follow up its authentication system

Comment: @RikardOlsson At the end of my original post I have added the output of the php artisan route:list statment and some details about my routes, please you can see it and give me more details? :-)

Comment: I think as mentioned in my last comment that the views are generated when running `php artisan make:auth`. But before doing that I would do a `commit` if I were you ;) I'm not sure how much is auto generated and in your case *overwritten*

Comment: @RikardOlsson So do you thino that using the "php artisan make:auth" statment the view and rout for login will created and that it uses my custom user provider to perorm the user authentication?

Comment: I'm pretty sure about the views and routes, but not for using you custom user provider. If the provider is set up correctly I believe it should work. Laravel is built to easily replace different parts to fit your application